# Connecting to https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid: Access is denied

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, multi-factor-authentication

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following
error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

- MFA in Azure AD is disabled, however, the administrator is prompted to enter the MS Authenticator app password - how can I disable it? 
  [image]
- If it's not possible I have an app registration and have both client ID and secret but I cannot just enter my admin user account + app secret when I enter $UserCredential = Get-credential
  [image]
- There is no conditional access in Conditional Access - Policies:
  [image]
- When the new user signs in - he's prompted to enter security info:
  [image]

Comment: Hi feedthemachine, any updates from your side? If you have any further question, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score -1):

> New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server
>   outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access
>   is denied.

This issue occurs for one of the following reasons:

- You enter an incorrect user name or password. You try to sign in to
- the service by using an account that doesn't have access to Exchange 
  Online.

To resolve this issue, use the Exchange admin center in Office 365 to add the user as a member of the administrator role group. Follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/connecting-to-the-service/access-denied-connect-powershell#solution).

> MFA in Azure AD is disabled, however, the administrator is prompted to
>   enter the MS Authenticator app password - how can I disable it?

Check this [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/turn-off-2-factor-authentication/638899e0-185b-4942-98ee-63773a275ee5) to learn how to disable 2-factor authentication.